# ExportAsFixedFormat - store the new pdf in an object

Tags: excel, vba, object

I am using the code:

```
ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
  Filename:=strFilename, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
  IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
  OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

to export a specific worksheet as a pdf.

Afterwards I want to use the file to sent it via email and then delete it.

For this I thought it would be great if I could save the file as an object and this is where I am struggling.

Any recommendations?

Comment: You've got the filename, shouldn't that be enough? (thinking you're going to use [`Attachments.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add))

Comment: What do you mean by "save the file as an object"? What do you need to with the object and/or what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Hi Daniel, we try to keep questions extremely to-the-point on here so I've gone ahead and trimmed yours down a bit.  If you aren't happy with my changes, feel free to edit it again.

Comment: Are you asking if you can export as PDF to memory instead of to disk?  AFAIK that's not possible from excel.  Nothing wrong with using a temp file for this.

Comment: thank you for your comments! I know how to use the pdf with the path. I just want to know how I could save it as an object for further handling (even if it is not neccessary).

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the file to disk and then make a note of the path and use something similar to below.

```
Sub SendEmail()

    Dim outlookApp As Object
    Dim outlookMail As Object
    Dim sigString As String
    Dim Signature As String
    Dim insertPDF As String

    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outlookMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)

    'Change only Mysig.htm to the name of your signature
    sigString = Environ("appdata") & _
                "\Microsoft\Signatures\Marius.htm"

    If Dir(sigString) <> "" Then
        Signature = GetBoiler(sigString)
    Else
        Signature = ""
    End If

    insertPDF = "C:\Users\marius\Desktop\Presale.PDF" 'your PDF path

    emailMessage = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>Dear " & titleName & " " & fullName & "," & _
                    "<p>I hope my email will find you very well." & _
                    "<p>Our <strong>sales preview</strong> starts on Thursday the 22nd until Sunday the 25th of November." & _
                    "<p>I look forward to welcoming you into the store to shop on preview.<p>" & _
                    "<p> It really is the perfect opportunity to get some fabulous pieces for the fast approaching festive season." & _
                    "<p>Please feel free to contact me and book an appointment." & _
                    "<p>I look forward to seeing you then." & _
                    "<p>Kind Regards," & _
                    "<br>" & _
                    "<br><strong>Marius</strong>" & _
                    "<br>Assistant Store Manager" & _
                    "<p>"


    With outlookMail
        .To = clientEmail
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "PRIVATE SALE"
        .BodyFormat = 2
        .Attachments.Add insertPDF, 1, 0
        .HTMLBody = emailMessage & Signature
        .Importance = 2
        .ReadReceiptRequested = True
        .Display
        .Send

    End With

    Set outlookApp = Nothing
    Set outlookMail = Nothing
End Sub
Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    GetBoiler = ts.readall
    ts.Close
End Function
```